# Combine the dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
>>> data    
    Name  Score
0    a      3
1    b      2
2    a      1
3    c      4
4    c      5
5    d      3
```

I want to combine the rows with same name, adding score rows, so I want to get the following result:

```
    Name  Score
0    a      4
1    b      2    
2    c      9   
3    d      3
```

Is there an effective solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.groupby('Name').sum()['Score'].reset_index()
```

Comment: `data.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index()` would just work here